# Clear data inside all files in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, fstream

Hi guys I am programming on C++. I wish to clear all the data inside of all files in the current directory. Can someone tell me the command to get all files?

That is what I am trying but it doesn't work:

```
ofs.open("*.*", ios::out | ios::trunc);
```

The problem is: `open("*.*",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fstream can't open all files of a directory, instead, you can iterate each file. 
This example only works on C++17

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <filesystem>
    #include <fstream>
    //namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; //for visual studio
    namespace fs = std:::filesystem;
    int main()
    {
        std::string path = "path_to_directory";
        for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
            if (fs::is_regular_file(p)){
                std::fstream fstr;
                fstr.open(p.path().c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
                //do something
                fstr.close()
            }
        }
    }
```

Older compilers(Windows):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


std::wstring path = L"path_to_directory";

path += L"\\*";
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
HANDLE hFind;
if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(path.c_str(), &data)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
        if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) {
            std::fstream fstr;
            fstr.open(data.cFileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
            //do something
            fstr.close();
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data) != 0);
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Comment: thanks mate but that doesn't work at all.. https://i.imgur.com/li6azNC.png

Comment: Namespacename is not allowed.

Comment: You need a C++17 compiler, instead you need opendir()/readdir() functions in dirent.h header for linux